# How to make Nginx virtualhosts work? (currently gives 403 Forbidden error)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, virtualhost

I want to run nginx on my Ubuntu 10.04 32bit Linode VPS.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/development
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

To make a nginx virtualhost:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/example.com/{public,logs}
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

and wrote following

```
server {
     listen   80;
     server_name  www.example.com;
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
     }

server {
     listen   80;
     server_name example.com;

     access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
     error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

     location / {
          root   /var/www/example.com/public/;
          index  index.html;
          }
}
```

Then I enabled the virtualhost example.com

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

I put a index.html to `/var/www/example.com/public` and enter example.com URL from my browser. Then I got following

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/0.8.53
```

`tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` gives following error

```
*38 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 88.224.1.128, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: www.example.com
```

I redo

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

but it gives same error.

and cat /etc/nginx/nginx.cnf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    gzip  on;
    # As per: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipModule#gzip_disable starting
    # with 0.7.63
    gzip_disable     "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

If I put the index.html to /var/www/ then I can see html file but any attempt to put it under /var/www/example.com/public fails. I looked at file and folder permissions they are ok all belongs to www-data and readable (775)

What can I do to make nginx work? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is probably another file in the sites-enabled directory, with a servername wildcard? And my guess is that this configuration has a root directory of "/var/www"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload the configuration files? Nginx does not parse the configuration file on every load like Apache does with htaccess, you have to actively send it the reload (HUP) command.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu the reload command will be

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

If installed via apt, if not then try

```
/path/to/nginx reload
```